# Datapie: gaps between slices

Tags: datatool

I need to remove the gap between the green and cyan slices as shown below:
[image: Pie chart]

Mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datapie}

\begin{filecontents}{test.csv}
Name,Quantity
"Apples",30
"Pears",25
"Lemons,Limes",40.5
"Peaches",34.5
"Cherries",20
\end{filecontents}

\DTLloaddb{fruit}{test.csv}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{1}{blue}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{2}{red}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{3}{green}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{4}{cyan}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{5}{pink}
\DTLpiechart{variable=\quantity,outerlabel=\name}{fruit}{%
\name=Name,\quantity=Quantity}
\caption{A pie chart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The gap is in the sample document of the `datatool` package too. It looks like a bug

Comment: the gap exists in version 2016/28/07

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by a rounding error where real numbers were truncated to integers. It's now fixed in version 2.26.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datapie}[2016/07/20]

\begin{filecontents}{test.csv}
Name,Quantity
"Apples",30
"Pears",25
"Lemons,Limes",40.5
"Peaches",34.5
"Cherries",20
\end{filecontents}

\DTLloaddb{fruit}{test.csv}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{1}{blue}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{2}{red}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{3}{green}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{4}{cyan}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{5}{pink}
\DTLpiechart{variable=\quantity,outerlabel=\name}{fruit}{%
\name=Name,\quantity=Quantity}
\caption{A pie chart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: image of pie chart]